# Automatic logout when login in other site in the same server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We develop 2 sites in asp.net, this both use forms authentication, when a user login in one of this sites it work fine, but if login into the second site, it's logout for the server of the first site, the authentication of both sites have the same usecontrol.

thanks

Comment: I'm guessing, although you didn't explicitly state it, that you want to prevent logout from one site when you log into another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you using Forms Authentication?  Are you using cookies?  If so, you might need to associate the cookie to the domain name.  Something like this:

```
Dim c As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name.ToString, False)
c.Domain = "webiste.com"
Response.AppendCookie(c)
```